# What is the usual way in MATLAB to read help page by page?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for an equivalent of for example DOS's *dir |more* which lists the data, until one page is complete, then waits for a key to be pressed until showing another. Is there an equivalent for MATLAB's help system.

I know I could simply scroll back, but this would be so much more convenient, expecially if one uses help system often.

Comment: Is it really something that obvious; therefore the downvote?

Comment: It's not obvious per se, but a '>> help help', followed by '>> help more' would have gotten you what you needed. The fact of using help on help did amuse me though.

Comment: in old versions of matlab "help help" would return "I'm drowning!" but at some point they lost their sense of humor

why is still pretty good though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type `more on` at the command line. This will print command outputs page by page.

For the next line: 'return'; next page; 'spacebar'; return to command line: 'q'.

Likewise,  `more off` resumes the normal display mode.